# ajax response a django form using HttpResponse

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

My ajax function has response django form.

```
in views.py code,
..
..
dictionary={'userform':userform,'info_form':info_form}
return HttpResponse(dictionary)
```

but when I alert on console.log the response it is something like..
`userforminfo_form`. I can not parse in json type at both client n sever side. 
how to httpresponse a form object. When i trying to do json.dump, it gives me error that, json object is not serializable.
thanx!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. its unclear what you're asking

Comment: I just want to pass django form in httpresponse..

Comment: So what isn't working? What does your code currently do? What is your *actual* view code? What does ajax have to do with your question? What does jquery have to do with it? or json?

Comment: @Sayse I just want this two lines to run dictionary={'userform':userform,'info_form':info_form}
return HttpResponse(dictionary) ...and the response form has to use in client side...like we have render a response django form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from django.core import serializers` and you can parse data coming from database then and the create dict and and pass this dict to HttpResponse

```
`userform = serializers.serialize('json', userform)`
`dictionary={'userform':userform}`
`HttpResponse(json.dumps(dictionary),content_type="application/json"`)
```

If it's doesn't work we have to parse data and create list from that as follows

```
array=[]
for a in data;
    array.append(a)
dictionary={'userform':array}
HttpResponse(json.dumps(dictionary),content_type="application/json")
```